# Run Firestore batch in Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

In Cloud Functions for Firebase, I am trying to run admin.firestore.batch(), but I am receiving error "admin.firestore.batch is not a function", see (totally simplified) example.

```
exports.getTest = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  cors(request, response, () => {
    var batch = admin.firestore.batch(); // <--- ERROR HERE
    var docRef = admin.firestore().doc('tariffs/1')
    batch.set(docRef, 'name', 'free');
    return batch.commit();
  }).then(() => {
    response.status(200).send({result: 'success'});
  });
});
```

My package.json is

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "dependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.1",
    "firebase-admin": "^5.4.2",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.7.1"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Is it possible to use firebase.firestore.batch() with Cloud Functions?

Thank you

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You are missing the `()` after `admin.firestore`.

Change this:

```
var batch = admin.firestore.batch(); // <--- ERROR HERE
```

to this:

```
var batch = admin.firestore().batch();
```

Comment: Oh god, such a silly mistake... Thank you, Bob Snyder